# AuthenticationCertCallback does not work under Ubuntu / docker

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I have problem with Certificate Key Vault authentication. In general, it works fine under my pc (win10), but when I run the same code under ubuntu/ docker I receive null reference exception. (On both environments, the certificate is present)

```
private async Task<string> AuthenticationCertCallback(string authority, string resource, string scope)
        {
            try
            {
                var clientAssertionCertPfx = CertificateHelper.FindCertificateByThumbprint(_options.KeyVaultOptions.CertThumb);
                var assertionCert = new ClientAssertionCertificate(_options.KeyVaultOptions.Id, clientAssertionCertPfx);
                var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
                var token = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, assertionCert);
                return token.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "Failed to acquire the certificate");
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

I use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.0"

had anyone same problem ?

Comment: What does `FindCertificateByThumbprint` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue is with GetRSAPrivateKey() from X502Certificate2 class as it returns null under .net core